# used 'ignore' to pass the compiler

Tags: ocaml

This is a function that I computed an equivalence class is a set of elements that are all equivalent. Intended to instead iterate over all entries in the matrix column; compute an equivalence class with relations reflexive and check both directions

```
let eq_class m i =
  let column = m.(i)
  and set = ref [] in
  Array.iteri begin fun j l ->
    if j = i || column.(j) && m.(j).(i) then
      set := j :: !set else ignore l
  end column;
  !set;;
```

Could you please explain for me about `l`, I have to used `ignore` to pass the compiler. How can I write this function correct at `l` without using `ignore` ?

Comment: I get `File "m.ml", line 6, characters 37-38:
Error: Syntax error` on your example.

Comment: I think it because I have 'ignore l' in my code. Thanks I fixed it at the ignore l.

Answer (score 8):

You can replace `ignore l` with `()` : it has the same type and does the same thing (nothing).

The expression in the `else` branch should have the same type as the expression in the `then` branch, and the type of the expression in the `then` branch is `unit`.

Furthermore, there is a shortened convenience construct for `if condition then expression else ()`. The shorter equivalent construct is `if condition then expression`, which you can use in your program:

```
let eq_class m i =
  let column = m.(i)
  and set = ref [] in
  Array.iteri begin fun j l ->
    if j = i || column.(j) && m.(j).(i) then
      set := j :: !set
  end column;
  !set;;
```